Number of arrangements of "AABCXX" without "AA" and "C" isn't next to "A" or "B".
I'm trying to use the Goulden-Jackson cluster method with the alphabet $V=\{A,B,C,X\}$ and forbidden bad words $\{ AA, AC, CA, BC, CB\}$. I also want to keep track of how many of each letter there are, so I'm using the weights $a,b,c,x$. Solving for the cluster thingy I get the following
$$Weight(\mathcal C) =
\left(1,\,  1,\,1,\,1,\,1\right)\left(\begin{array}{rrrrr}
a + 1 & 0 & a & 0 & 0 \\
a & 1 & a & 0 & 0 \\
0 & c & 1 & c & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & b \\
0 & c & 0 & c & 1
\end{array}\right)^{-1}
\left(\begin{array}{r}
a^{2} \\a c \\ a c \\ b c \\ b c 
\end{array}\right) \\
=
\frac{a^{3} c - a^{2} b c - a b^{2} c - 3 a b c^{2} + b^{2} c^{2} - a^{3} + 2 a b c - b^{2} c - 2 a c^{2} - 2 b c^{2} + a^{2} + 2 a c + 2 b c}{a b c + a c + b c - a - 1}
$$
And then the generating function is
$$
f(a,b,c,x) = \frac{1}{1-a-b-c-x-Weight(\mathcal C)} \\
= \frac{a b c + a c + b c - a - 1}{-a^{3} c + 2 a b c^{2} - b^{2} c^{2} - a b c x + a^{3} - a^{2} c - 3 a b c + a c^{2} + b c^{2} - a c x - b c x + a b - b c + a x + b + c + x - 1}
$$
But extracting the coefficient of $a^2bcx^2$, I get the nonsensical value $-12$. The correct number should be $18$.
Here's the Sage-code I'm using:
R.<a,b,c,x> = PolynomialRing(QQ, 4)
Bs = ['aa', 'ac', 'ca', 'bc', 'cb']
toVar = {'a': a, 'b': b, 'c':c, 'x':x}
mat = matrix.identity(len(Bs)) + matrix(R, [[ (toVar[bi[0]] if bi[0]==bj[1] else 0) for bj in Bs] for bi in Bs])
bVec = -vector(R, tuple(toVar[b[0]]*toVar[b[1]] for b in Bs))
C = sum(mat^(-1)*bVec)
T = taylor(1/(1-a-b-c-x-C), (a,0), (b,0), (c,0), (x,0), 6)
print (T.coefficient(a**2*b*c*x**2))

What goes wrong here?

Seems like a lot of work for such a small set of permutations.  I'd work by cases, according to where the $C$ falls.  Either the word begins $CX$, ends $XC$ or contains $XCX$.  Count each case.

@lulu Yes, it's an overkill :D But this is just a small example and for the general case there will be more letters and restrictions what can be next to each other. But I couldn't get even this small case to work.

You made a mistake in the matrix that you used to find $\text{Weight}(\mathcal C)$. The rows and columns of this matrix should be labeled with the forbidden words, in the same order. Then, the entry of matrix at the row labeled $v$ and at the column labeled $u$ should be $u:v$, as defined in the paper. Remember that to calculate $u:v$, you look at all of the ways that a nonempty suffix of $u$ overlaps with a nonempty prefix of $v$; for each of these overlaps, $\ell$, you add up $\text{weight}(v/\ell)$, which is the result of removing the overlapping prefix from $v$. It looks like you were instead using the overlap itself as the matrix entry.
The correct matrix is as follows. Each nonzero, off-diagonal entry has a variable which corresponds to the second letter of the label of the row. In your work, each entry had a variable which corresponded to the overlapping letter of the row and column label.
$$
\begin{array}{c|ccccc}
&AA&AC&CA&BC&CB
\\\hline
AA & 1+a & 0 & a & 0 & 0
\\
AC & c & 1 & c & 0 & 0
\\
CA & 0 & a & 1 & a & 0
\\
BC & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & c
\\
CB & 0 & b & 0 & b & 1 
\end{array}
$$
When you make this correction in your sage code, you should get the correct answer of $18$. Here is an implementation in Mathematica: Try it online!.
Also, to be crystal clear, there is a second mistake in the MathJax part of your question; the column vector is supposed to be negated. However, you got this correct in your Sage code (you included the minus sign in the definition of bVec).
